# Calling External WCF Service in a SilverLight Application

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am having this problem

An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/Service1/'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details.

Can someone please help?

I am using SilverLight 4.0 and VS 2010 / .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution, and I decided to blog about it:
http://myspexp.com/2010/06/28/silverlight-wcf-web-service/